# Continuing power during 50ms power interrupt

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply

I have a system that is powered with 3-5 VDC but there are 50ms gaps where power is interrupted and I would like the system to continue running normally when that happens.  At 3.3V, the current may have very brief peaks of 1A, but usually is a quarter of that.

How can I prevent this power interrupt from crashing my system?  Would a capacitor in parallel with the power source work?  If so, what size cap?  Other ideas?  I don't want to bridge much more than a 50ms gap because I want it to sometimes shut off purposefully

Comment: Cap won't work for 1A with such a long disconnect. Where is the 3.3V coming from? It is always better to put a hold-up capacitor on the higher and unregulated voltage than on the regulated voltage. If the 3.3V is coming from a regulator, it may be better to put a capacitor on the input to that regulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate voltage drop versus time as i = C dv/dt. If i=1A, dt = 0.05seconds, and you didn't want more than, say, dv = 2V (voltage drop during cutout). Then C = i * dt / dv = 1 * 0.05/2 = 0.025 farads. That's a very large capacitor. Depending on what you are up to, it might be easier to diode-OR in an auxiliary power supply. 50ms is a long down time if there's an appreciable amount of current draw.

Comment: 3.3 V supercaps and ultracaps are quite reasonably priced and sized for this sort of application.

Comment: @DaveTweed Indeed so. I was working with them a decade ago. Typical part: https://csicapacitors.com/3000f-ultracapacitor/

Comment: @PeterSmith: That might be a bit of overkill here :-) I was thinking more in terms of devices in the range of 0.2 to 1.0 F that are about the size and shape of a coin cell.

Comment: @DaveTweed I had to test some to destruction to assess the potential use case for power holdup in avionics. I could have sold tickets :)

Comment: @Peter Smith would that more of electronics were such a spectator sport.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify how low the supply can go before your circuit resets, or how your supply is structured, but one thing you can do is use a small battery in parallel with your normal supply both feeding the power rail via diodes.

You may be able to get a modest size cap in parallel with two CR2023 in series as your backup supply.  The CR2032 will only put out about 0.1A but in parallel with a capacitor, they may just do the trick.

Alternatively, you may consider regular primary batteries such as AAA or 1/2AA which would more than cover the current but you need to make sure your circuit works at the voltage produced by these batteries minus the diode drop.